# netty reuse channels

Tags: netty, channel

i want to create a connection pool that reuse channels but i couldn't figure out

executing this test

```
public void test() {


    ClientBootstrap client = new ClientBootstrap(new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

    client.setPipelineFactory(new ClientPipelineFactory());

    // Connect to server, wait till connection is established, get channel to write to
    Channel channel = client.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.252.152", 8080)).awaitUninterruptibly().getChannel();
    {
        // Writing request to channel and wait till channel is closed from server
        HttpRequest request = new DefaultHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.POST, "test");

        String xml = "xml document here";
        ChannelBuffer buffer = ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(msgXml, Charset.defaultCharset());
        request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_LENGTH, buffer.readableBytes());
        request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/xml");
        request.setContent(buffer);

        channel.write(request).awaitUninterruptibly().getChannel().getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();

        channel.write(request).awaitUninterruptibly().getChannel().getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();
    }
    client.releaseExternalResources();

}
```

I got an ClosedChannelException in the second channel.write(request)....

Exist a way to reuse the channels? or remain the channel open?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the second write failed is because the server closed the connection.

The reason the server closed the connection is because you failed to add the HTTP header

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

to the original request.

This is required in order to leave the channel open (which is what you want to do in this scenario).

Once a channel has been closed, you **must** create a new channel.  You *cannot* reopen the channel.  The ChannelFuture returned by Channel.getCloseFuture() is final (i.e., constant) to the channel and once isDone() on this future returns `true` it cannot be reset.  This is the reason that a closed channel cannot be reused.

However, you may reuse an open channel as many times as you need; but your application must talk the HTTP protocol properly in order to accomplish this.